# How to know if requestor connection closed/disconnected from client side, Python Pyramid

Tags: python, backend, pyramid

From front-end side I have a searchbox which sends GET request after every new change detected in the text field. To disregard the response if new string has been detected I simply do a cancel on my previous axios GET request if its still in process before making a new one.

Example:

```
Text Field = i
GET i
Text Field = ie
Cancel GET i if still waiting for response
GET ie
Text Field = ie1
Cancel GET ie1 if still waiting for response
GET ie1
```

On backend i keep getting Broken Pipeline error. My restful api is made in python using pyramid and need help with canceling trying to send response back if connection closes.

How can i get pyramid to check if the request client connection is still open or not. Or what is some other solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to check if a connection is open or not.

Most web servers are designed to hard close / kill thread / kill process running the HTTP request. The request itself cannot know if the client has somehow disconnected until it tries to write the request.

The best is to ignore this problem and configure your logging so that these hanging requests do not cause verbose output.